# Combining ionice and nice in Linux, and transitive priorities

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I want to load use both ionice (I/O priority) and nice (process priority) to start-up a program.

I see variations of this line all over the internet:

```
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n19 [my program to run]
```

(or)

```
nice -n19 ionice -c2 -n7 [my program to run]
```

Everyone lists it without any elaboration.

My question is... how does ionice (the first program) setting the priorities of nice (the second program), affect the third program (the program I want to run)? Are the priorities transitive when a program starts another program?

A quick test with htop appears to actually confirm that this works correctly. The program run will have 19 niceness in both cases--which is great, it's what we want to happen. But how is it working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you start your *program* (assuming it's a simple single-process program), you get 1 *process* running your program. So far so good.

`nice` is a special program that start another program with an adjusted niceness. When you start `nice -n 19 someprogram` the system (actually the shell) starts a new process to execute `nice`, but that new process does not in turn execute `someprogram` in a new process: it **replaces the current process image (`nice`) with a new process image (`someprogram`)**.

Same with `ionice`. So `nice -n19 ionice -c2 -n7` starts `nice` first, which does its thing then starts `ionice` (replacing its own process image), which does its own thing then finally starts `someprogram` (replacing its own process image), resulting in a single process that has adjusted CPU and IO niceness.

That being said, since [a child process inherits whatever `nice` value is held by the parent at the time that it is forked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37901/232282), it would still be true if `nice`/`ionice` did fork a child process.

So :

> Are the priorities transitive when a program starts another program?

Yes, in both situations (process image replacement & child process creation).